# How to remove the camera feed in ARSCNView?

Tags: ios, camera, arscnview

I'd like to replace the camera feed in ARSCNView as the camera quality is not as good as the native camera feed.

Does anyone know how to remove the camera feed in ARSCNView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above answer does not work for me

```
sceneView.scene.background.contents = UIColor.clear
```

does work for me though

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this on an instance of `ARSCNView`:

```
scene.background.contents = nil
```